# django or extjs , encode another site post

Tags: django, extjs, openlayers

i am working with openlayers, extjs , django

is there any way taking another site post and do sth. with django or extjs...

for exam. from another site you click button it sends xy coordinate and my main site will catch the data and add the xy data ...

when i click the link http://www.ppp.com/frmOL=OL&Point&x=36.555&y=33.665 will be create , i will cath the data ,encode and than add the data to map

thanks for your help

Comment: Do you mean host another site not on the same domain and intercept calls?

Comment: i dont understand what you mean but i want to catch data of another site inducement...

Comment: It would be easier to help if your question was easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get the data from the query string, process it and add it to your database.